# Convert JSON array format to different JSON format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I am working on expressJS app and I need to send post request to url.
I am using sequelize and get datas from mssql database table.
My datas coming like `[ { "x":"data1", "y":"data2", "z":1, "w":3 } ]`

In the api documentation, I must post data just like `{ "x":"data1", "y":"data2", "z":1, "w":3 }` this type.

I don't know how can I convert ? What are differences of both type ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The first one is an array. Looks like you just want to forward the first entry from that array to the API

Comment: use `findOne` instead of `find`, or pull out the object from the array, `result = result[0] || {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[{ x: "data1", y: "data2", z: 1, w: 3 }]
```

Above snippet is an array. You want to convert it into object. So you can use array index to get data i.e. `object` from an array.

```js
const array = [{
  x: "data1",
  y: "data2",
  z: 1,
  w: 3
}];
const obj = array[0];
console.log(obj);
```